# Clickable Button inside 'a' Tag

Tags: javascript, css, button, href

When I click tag `<button>`, tag `<a>` clicked directly. How to solve it? or any other way?
[image]

Comment: Wheres the js code?

Comment: Would love to help, if you share your code

Comment: [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: Why do you have a button inside of an `a` tag? but it can be fixed with @Satpal instruction

Comment: when I click tag `<image>` it direct to another page with tag `<a>`.

Comment: You have to add event.stopPropagation() at the very beginning in your click event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tag `<button>` is child of tag `<a>`, that's why tag `<a>` clicked when you click `<button>`. Create tag `<button>` as sibling of tag `<a>` and position it over image with the help of css.

```
<a href="#">
   <image src="">
</a>
<button>View<button>
```

Also use higher z-index for `<button>` to make it over tag `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks, it work.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that's not possible. But, you can try removing the `<a>` tag or add `pointer-events: none` to the `<a>` tag.

The reason is, you're enclosed the button with a link tag. This make the button a link. So, clicking the button will trigger a click event on the enclosing link.

This can be handled via `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` in JavaScript.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I need tag `<a>` clickable when I click tag `<image>` it redirect to another page, called `detail.php`.

Comment: Its possible mate, but not recommended